# Passing StringBuilder::append as argument in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, append, stringbuilder

I'm using [BIP39 plugin](https://github.com/NovaCrypto/BIP39#generate-a-mnemonic) for Java to create a mnemonic.
So I've converted (well mostly IDEA did) [this Java code](https://github.com/NovaCrypto/BIP39#generate-a-mnemonic) to a function in Kotlin syntax which looks like this:

```kotlin
fun mnemonicBuilder(): String {
  val sb = StringBuilder()
  val entropy = ByteArray(Words.TWELVE.byteLength())
  SecureRandom().nextBytes(entropy)
  MnemonicGenerator(English.INSTANCE)
      .createMnemonic(entropy, sb::append)
  return sb.toString()
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA keeps telling me that "***None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.***" for **sb::append**.

My quess is that [.createMnemonic requires](https://github.com/NovaCrypto/BIP39/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/novacrypto/bip39/MnemonicGenerator.java#L78) the second argument to have [no return value (given by Target interface)](https://github.com/NovaCrypto/BIP39/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/novacrypto/bip39/MnemonicGenerator.java#L45) but all appenders return the StringBuilder as a value.

Please, can somebody help me?

Comment: There is a concise [Kotlin implementation of bip-39](https://github.com/zcash/kotlin-bip39) that you might find helpful so that you're not having to rely on IntelliJ to convert Java to Kotlin. I created it to support Android wallet work and it is mainly based off a Rust-implementation from one of our in-house cryptographers who is a co-author on the BIP-39 spec. The library has also passed review by our security team. So hopefully it is useful. If not, file an issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, argument signatures do not match. You can solve it by using lambda instead of the method reference:

```kotlin
MnemonicGenerator(English.INSTANCE)
    .createMnemonic(entropy) { sb.append(it) }
```